# SetConsoleMode returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when disabling quick edit mode

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I am trying to disable quick edit mode in the console with winapi. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) says:

> To enable this mode, use ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS. To disable this mode, use ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS without this flag.

I expected this code to work:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    HANDLE console = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(console);

    if (!SetConsoleMode(console, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS))
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    for (;;);

    return 0;
}
```

But I can still select in the console and it prints `87` which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592932/10372572) but I got the same results.

I am using clang version 10.0.0

Comment: `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` is a valid flag "*if the hConsoleHandle parameter is an input handle*" but your `console` is a console screen buffer, instead. See the first paragraph under [SetConsoleMode parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode#parameters).

Comment: @dxiv you're right I had to use `SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS)`. If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `SetConsoleMode` is a handle to either "*the console input buffer or a console screen buffer*" per the [linked docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode#parameters).

`ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` is part of the set of flags which apply to an input handle, only, but the `console` handle in the posted code is a console screen buffer, instead.

To set or change the quick edit mode, the call must use an [input buffer handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer), which is usually obtained with `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`, or `CreateFile` with the reserved name `"CONIN$"` which [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/what-does-createfileconin-do) even in case the standard input was redirected.